# Converting minutes and seconds in seconds

Tags: php, datetime, converting

I have 2 input fields to input the duration of a CD song. The first input is for minutes and the second is for seconds

When submitting the form, I must insert in the db the duration either in seconds (minutes + seconds) or `NULL`.

Here's my validation formula:

```
$warning = array();

function val_duration($min, $sec, $required = false) {
    global $warning;

    if (!empty($min) || !empty($sec)) {

        if (!empty($min) && (!is_numeric($min) || !ctype_digit($min) || $min > 60)) {
            $warning['min'] = 'The minutes must contain a positive numeric value between 1 and 60';
        } else {
            $min_in_sec = $min * 60;
        }

        if (!empty($sec) && (!is_numeric($sec) || !ctype_digit($sec) || $sec > 59)) {
            $warning['sec'] = 'The seconds must contain a positive numeric value between 1 and 59';
        } else {
            $tmpsec = $sec;
        }

        $value = $min_in_sec + $tmpsec;

    } else {

        if ($required) {
            $warning['duration'] = "The duration is a required field";
        }

        $value = NULL;
    }

    return $value;
}


// HTML 
<input id="min" name="min" type="text" value="...">
<input id="sec" name="sec" type="text" value="...">

// validate
$min = ltrim(trim($_POST['min']), '0');
$sec = ltrim(trim($_POST['sec']), '0');

$duration_in_secs = val_duration($min, $sec, true); // duration

// mySQL
enter $duration_in_secs in db (either seconds or NULL)
```

Comment: `$warning` doesn't seem to be accessible outside of the function?

Comment: true. i edited my code...

Comment: Is the maximum length of the song 59 minutes 59 seconds? And what if the user wants to input 2.5 minutes as `150 seconds` (maybe they are getting that info in total seconds from a different source/app and don't want to make the conversion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips:

- The name of the function should be clearer.
- Try to avoid `ctype_digit` usage, because it may produce unexpected results - `ctype_digit(42)` returns `FALSE`.
- Because you are working with integers, you should cast values to integers. Note that inputs are always strings.
- You must check for negative values as well.
- Second can be 0. For example: 2 min and 0 sec. Also, some songs can last less than a minute (classic songs)
- Consider that some CD songs may have a duration of more than 60 mins, CD medium can store 80 mins (and it can be one song), and some mix or classic songs. So, maybe you should avoid a minute check.

```
<?php
$warning = array();


/**
 * Validate song duration
 * @param $min
 * @param $sec
 * @param $required
 * @return int|NULL
 */
function validate_duration($min, $sec, $required = false) {
    global $warning;

    $min = (int) $min;
    $sec = (int) $sec;

    if($required && $min == 0 && $sec == 0) {
        $warning['duration'] = "The duration is a required field.";
        return NULL;
    }

    if($sec < 0 OR $sec > 59) {
        $warning['sec'] = 'The seconds must be between 0 and 59';
    }

    if($min < 0 OR $min > 60) {
        $warning['min'] = 'The minutes must be between 0 and 60';
    }

    // for songs bigger then 60 minutes
    if($min == 60 && $sec > 0) {
        $warning['duration'] = "Song must last more then one second and maximum 60 minutes.";
    }

    return !empty($warning) ? $min * 60 + $sec : NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. I'm not familiar with PHP too much but [globals are usually considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/843804). I don't know what's the best practice in PHP but passing the `$warning` argument by reference seems a good idea here.
2. When a field is not posted you get various PHP notices. I guess it's better to avoid these notices:

   ```
   PHP Notice:  Undefined index: min in /tmp/x.php on line ...
   PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sec in /tmp/x.php on line ...
   ```

   A robust code should handle these cases.
3. `tmpsec` and `min_in_sec` are not initialized in every code paths, so you can get notices about these too when there is no `min` key in the `$_POST` array:

   ```
   PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: tmpsec in /tmp/x.php on line 24
   PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: min_in_sec in /tmp/x.php on line 2
   ```

   I think it's cleaner to initialize all variables. It also could help debugging since you don't have to ignore lots of PHP notice messages when you are looking for an [uninitialized global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/843804).
4. `tmpsec` and `min_in_sec` could be omitted if you reorganize the code to not count anything until it is sure that there isn't any input error. (See below.)
5. A small note: The function is a little bit inconsistent: it allows `60` as minute but doesn't as seconds. It would be cleaner and more common to set one hour as hours = 1, minutes = 0 and seconds = 0.

```
$warning = array();

function val_duration(&$warning, $min, $sec, $required = false) {
    if (empty($min) && empty($sec)) {
        if ($required) {
            $warning['duration'] = "The duration is a required field";
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!ctype_digit($min) || $min > 61) {
        $warning['min'] = 'The minutes must contain a positive numeric value between 1 and 60';
    }
    if (!ctype_digit($sec) || $sec > 59) {
        $warning['sec'] = 'The seconds must contain a positive numeric value between 1 and 59';
    }
    if (!empty($warning)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return $min * 60 + $sec;
}
```

Comment: val_duration($warning, 1, 1) will produce warning. Also var_duration($warning, "-1", "10") will produce -70. See my answer.

Comment: @sasa: Thanks, I've not noticed this bug (it's in the original code too). Maybe I'm too tired but I could not reproduce the second one. It puts a message to the `warning` array and returns `NULL` instead of only returning `-70`.